# Divide two values obtained from EditText ad divide them by each other

Tags: android, math, numerical

Is it possible in Java code to divide two obtained values from two EditText boxes in an android app, and then divide them by each other to create a result?

Pretty much, the consumer of my application will be asked for two DIFFERENT, numerical values to be inputted into each box.

What I want to do with each value is produce a mathematical sum.
E.g.

If the first EditText box contains "22"
and the second EditText contains "11"
I want to be able to take those two values and divide them by each other to produce a value which I can further use.
In this case, that value produced would be 2.

22 / 11 = 2

I've already imported these two values into another Class (labeled DataHelper) through className.insert(stringName).

```
public class DataHelper extends Activity{

    public static void insert(String firstFB, String firstRL) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

}
```

That's the Class for DataHelper with the two String values.

I have tried using IEEEremainder(x, y), but I don't know exactly how to use it since I am a novice at this language.

Can anyone give me some help with this?  Any help at all will be appreciated.

Regards,
Mike.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if under standing rigtig you cut due

int one = int value1 / int vlaue2;

but then when you get the value from a edittext you get a string so you need to convert it to a int first int a = new Integer("value from edittext").intValue();

Comment: Have you got any idea how I can post the result of that to an XML file?

Comment: if you mean like the android UI then YES you just say like edittext.setTEXT(value); ore textview.setText(Value); if youre posting like an int sat ""+value

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want something like this:

```
public class DataHelper extends Activity{

    public static void insert(String firstFB, String firstRL) {
        int fb = Integer.parseInt(firstFB);
        int rl = Integer.parseInt(firstRL);

        int division = fb / rl; // Or use double if needed
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't see this reply first, but yes, that did work, so thank you for helping!  Can you tell me how I can export that result to be viewable on my app?  Paste the result into a TextView for example.  If you understand what I mean...